# Undefined object fields in javascript reducer function

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I'm learning spread operators, reducer functions, and some general data manipulation. Thanks to some help here on SO, I have a working function that reduces my data objects to show the most recent assessments by date, with ID. That works great. I've added two more fields to the assessment objects (cadence and assessmentName) but I'm getting undefined for those fields in the result. Where am I going wrong?

Here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kzffrx?file=index.js

```js
const result = data.map(({assessments, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  'assessments' : Object.entries(assessments
    .reduce((a, [{ id, date }]) => {
      a[id] = (a[id] || '').localeCompare(date) > 0 ? a[id] : date
      return a
    }, {}))
    .map(([id, date, cadence, assessmentName]) => ([{ id, date, cadence, assessmentName }]))
}))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
  {
    "partnerId": "p0001",
    "partnerName": "Foo",
    "assessments": [
        [ { "id": "a0016", "date": "2021-03-20", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FFIEC CAT Survey" } ],
        [ { "id": "a0016", "date": "2021-11-19", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FFIEC CAT Survey"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0011", "date": "2022-05-19", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FCC Risk Assessment"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0011", "date": "2020-10-29", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FCC Risk Assessment"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0001", "date": "2021-11-30", "cadence": "Semi-Annual", "assessmentName": "Counterparty & Financial Risk Assessments"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0001", "date": "2022-06-07", "cadence": "Semi-Annual", "assessmentName": "Counterparty & Financial Risk Assessments"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0013", "date": "2022-01-20", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FL Risk Assessment"  } ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "partnerId": "p0002",
    "partnerName": "Bar",
    "assessments": [
        [ { "id": "a004", "date": "2021-03-20", "cadence": "Semi-Annual", "assessmentName": "Model Governance" } ],
        [ { "id": "a003", "date": "2021-11-19", "cadence": "Quarterly", "assessmentName": "Credit Strategy"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a003", "date": "2022-05-19", "cadence": "Quarterly", "assessmentName": "Credit Strategy"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a003", "date": "2020-10-29", "cadence": "Quarterly", "assessmentName": "Credit Strategy"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0001", "date": "2021-11-30", "cadence": "Semi-Annual", "assessmentName": "Counterparty & Financial Risk Assessments"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0001", "date": "2022-06-07", "cadence": "Semi-Annual", "assessmentName": "Counterparty & Financial Risk Assessments"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0013", "date": "2022-01-20", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FL Risk Assessment"  } ]
    ]
  }
]
</script>
```

Comment: Your `.reduce((a, [{ id, date }])` discards the rest of the properties which aren't `id` or `date`. So, the `.map(([id, date, cadence, assessmentName])` doesn't actually have four things to destructure, just the first two.

Comment: I had previously added those properties to the reducer but the result was the same:
.reduce((a, [{ id, date, cadence, assessmentName }])

Comment: And did you return them after reducing? If you just accept them and still discard them, then...well, they wouldn't be there, would they?

Comment: I'm stuck on the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that it's not saving the values of `cadence` and `assessmentName` from each object, so they will end up undefined in the final object. You can fix this by storing the entire object in `a[id]` rather than just the date. Once you have done that you can use `Object.values` rather than `Object.entries` on the result of the reduce and just use `map` to put those values into their own array to achieve the nested structure of the input.

```js
const result = data.map(({assessments, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  'assessments' : Object.values(assessments
    .reduce((a, [obj]) => {
      const { id, date } = obj
      a[id] = (a[id]?.date || '').localeCompare(date) > 0 ? a[id] : obj
      return a
    }, {}))
    .map(obj => [obj])
}))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
  {
    "partnerId": "p0001",
    "partnerName": "Foo",
    "assessments": [
        [ { "id": "a0016", "date": "2021-03-20", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FFIEC CAT Survey" } ],
        [ { "id": "a0016", "date": "2021-11-19", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FFIEC CAT Survey"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0011", "date": "2022-05-19", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FCC Risk Assessment"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0011", "date": "2020-10-29", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FCC Risk Assessment"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0001", "date": "2021-11-30", "cadence": "Semi-Annual", "assessmentName": "Counterparty & Financial Risk Assessments"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0001", "date": "2022-06-07", "cadence": "Semi-Annual", "assessmentName": "Counterparty & Financial Risk Assessments"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0013", "date": "2022-01-20", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FL Risk Assessment"  } ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "partnerId": "p0002",
    "partnerName": "Bar",
    "assessments": [
        [ { "id": "a004", "date": "2021-03-20", "cadence": "Semi-Annual", "assessmentName": "Model Governance" } ],
        [ { "id": "a003", "date": "2021-11-19", "cadence": "Quarterly", "assessmentName": "Credit Strategy"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a003", "date": "2022-05-19", "cadence": "Quarterly", "assessmentName": "Credit Strategy"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a003", "date": "2020-10-29", "cadence": "Quarterly", "assessmentName": "Credit Strategy"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0001", "date": "2021-11-30", "cadence": "Semi-Annual", "assessmentName": "Counterparty & Financial Risk Assessments"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0001", "date": "2022-06-07", "cadence": "Semi-Annual", "assessmentName": "Counterparty & Financial Risk Assessments"  } ],
        [ { "id": "a0013", "date": "2022-01-20", "cadence": "Annual", "assessmentName": "FL Risk Assessment"  } ]
    ]
  }
]
</script>
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough @nick. I was really getting frustrated. I was definitely in the same zip code with regards to trying to store the object in a[id], but it is safe to say I may not have figured out the Object.values aspect, or at least not for a long time. I have a lot to learn. Thank you again.

Comment: @mediaguru no worries at all. I'm glad I could help.